# Defining recepientFilter for Exchange Web Services

Tags: exchange

I am using [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204095(v=exchg.140).aspx) to configure Exchange Impersonation for specific users or groups of users.

The command I am using is:

```
New-ManagementScope -Name:abc123 -RecipientRestrictionFilter:recipientFilter{Name -Eq ‘xyz’}
```

The error I am getting is:

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Name -Eq ‘xyz’’.
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ManagementScope], ParameterBindingException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,New-ManagementScope

I am not able to understand the problem.

Some people in answers highlight that we cannot use Name property with Recipient filter. But, the tutorial I followed clearly says:

> The RecipientRestrictionFilter parameter of the New-ManagementScope
>   cmdlet defines the members of the scope.  You can use properties of
>   the Identity object to create the filter.  The following example is a
>   filter that restricts the result to a single user with the user name
>   "john."
>
> ```
> Name –eq 'john'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not understand how the  New-ManagementScope should be used as it couldn´t handle the parameter "name". The best way would be to check the howtos [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335137(v=exchg.160).aspx) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204095(v=exchg.140).aspx).

From what I understand you wish to perform something like:

```
New-ManagementScope -Name "Protected Exec Users" -RecipientRestrictionFilter {Title -Like "*VP*" } -Exclusive
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -SecurityGroup "Executive Administrators" -Role "Mail Recipients" -CustomRecipientWriteScope "Protected Exec Users"
```